# refresh fragment view after getting synch service

Tags: android, android-fragments, synchronize

I have a synch service that runs at certain interval and updates the client side according to server data. Now if user does any changes to server data like removing a item from listview then that change should reflect to that corresponding view fragment.

The problem is - I am getting the changes in my fragment but that's not automatic. That means I have to go back and forth and come back to my relevant fragment to see my update.

Then how should I get notified from the synch service running in the background that my corresponding fragment view is now changed so that I can call my refresh function on my 
fragment view?

Note: I don't want to refresh the fragment again and again at certain intervals. I only want
      refresh when my fragment view gets changed.

UPDATE:

I am getting the adapter count that gives the count of a list view items in a fragment.
So whenever I gets the changed count, I need to update/refresh/reload the fragment. So my count will work as a trigger to change the fragment view.

Its something like:

```
if adapter.getCount() gets changed  //how to get notified about this change
{
        FragmentTransaction transactionOld =getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transactionOld.detach(this).commit();

     FragmentTransaction transactionNew = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transactionNew.attach(this).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in your `Fragment`, register it `onStart()` and unregister it in `onStop()`.

When your `SyncServices` has completed, and has updated the data, just send a broadcast using `sendBroadcast()`, to notify your `Fragment` if it is visible.

Of course, you will have to set a custom action for your `Broadcast`, like `com.myapp.ACTION_SYNC`, but you will learn this as you'll read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: can you please provide an example also in context as my fragment is already extending some other class so I can't do something like `class FragmentA extends BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: a fragment can not extend a `BroadcastReceiver`. It makes no sense. I can't understand what you are saying.

Comment: ok then I misunderstood in how to use `BroadcastReceiver` in a fragment. I thought to use it by extending it in a fragment and then to use it methods. Can you give some idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: kindly see my update too. I just need to update the view on adapter count. Any idea?

Comment: I can't understand. you won't be able to implement it in this way. What do you mean by "refresh/reload the fragment" ?

Comment: this is my own method which contains the logic to refresh the fragment to get the updated items in a list view. So no bother about that. This is just a skeleton code to get you the idea as what I need to accomplish.

Comment: you are modifiying the data in the adapter yourself. so you know when you change it... you don't need anything else. you won't be able to get notified when `getCount()` is changed..